# How do you use anchors for IDs in routes in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes, anchor

Imagine a blog with `posts` and `comments`. An individual comment's URL might be `posts/741/comments/1220`.

However, I'd like to make the URL `posts/741#1220`, or even `posts/741#comment-1230`.

What's the least intrusive way of doing this, so that `redirect_to comment_path(my_comment)` points to the correct URL?

Answer (score 69, accepted):

You could simply use

```
redirect_to post_path(comment.post, :anchor => "comment-#{comment.id}")
```

to manually build the URL with the anchor. That way, you can still have the absolute URL to your comments as `posts/:post_id/comments/:comment_id` in your routes. You can also create a helper method in e.g. application_controller.rb

```
class ApplicationController
  helper :comment_link

  def comment_link(comment)
    post_path(comment.post, :anchor => "comment-#{comment.id}")
  end
end
```

Comment: What would the benefit be of having my absolute URL still be posts/:post_id/comments/:comment_id?

Comment: @ClosureCowboy: You could still properly define the comments as resources, to e.g. delete or edit them. It depends on your actual requirements if this makes sense to have or not.

Comment: Is the controller really the best place to put this kind of helper? I'm pondering this issue myself and I don't really know where to put all my "anchor link helpers"

Comment: @AlexanderKuzmin You could also put it into a helper module. If you don't use the helper method in a controller action, you are fine then. Else you would have to include the helper module into your controller class by using `helper MyControllerHelper`.

Answer (score 1):

Prefer to keep your anchor builder in one place.

```
class Comment
  ...
  def anchor
    "comment-#{id}#{created_at.to_i}"
  end
end
```

then

```
post_path(comment.post, :anchor => comment.anchor)
```

Adding the `created_at.to_i` obscures your data a bit more and doesn't harm anything.