# Rails - routes.rb - scroll to anchor link for root page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

Is it possible to get the root page scroll to an anchor link when it loads the first time?

in my routes.rb file, i did

```
root :to => 'home#index#header' (#header being the anchor element in the index.html.erb)
```

But, obviously, that did not work.

Comment: `routes.rb` only specifies the controller and action to use, so you wouldn't specify the anchor there.

Answer (score 0):

You could do that in your controller by passing an `:anchor` parameter to any URL helper. See [How do you use anchors for IDs in routes in Rails 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4981029/how-do-you-use-anchors-for-ids-in-routes-in-rails-3) for a nice example.

You could also do that via javascript directly in the view (where it belongs IMO).

So no, I don't know a way to do that in your `routes.rb` but even if I did I would suggest against it. In your routes you are wiring incoming requests to controllers and actions. An HTML anchor is a view-related thing so it doesn't belong to `routes.rb`.

Comment: yeah i am aware of d :anchor parameter, but i like to know a method which will allow the root page, when first loaded, to scroll n show the anchor element

Comment: I proposed two alternative methods in my answer. Via a controller (with a redirect - render doesn't seem to accept an :anchor) or in the view itself.

Answer (score 0):

Use Javascript: (actually Coffeescript):

```
$(document).on 'turbolinks:load', ->
  window.location.hash = '#my_anchor'
```